# Extracting data from logs using Linux commands

Tags: linux

Hi I have file with logs in this format:

> 2017-09-13T11:08:27+02:00 {"log":"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m2017-09-13
>   11:07:58,443 |xte-8| INFO [org.springframework.Something] -
>   asdasdadasdsler] - Executing step: [asdsdsdp]\n"}

How to get rid of everything unneccessary and change \n to new lines so that it would look like this:

> [0m2017-09-13 11:07:58,443 |xte-8| INFO
>   [org.springframework.Something] - asdasdadasdsler] - Executing step:
>   [asdsdsdp]
>
> (new empty line from \n)

Using linux commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with regex to acomplish that:

```
sed -i -E 's/[\[A-z0-9\]:\+"]+(\[0m[0-9]{4}[^\\]+)\\n/$1/g' filename
```

What this does is:

- `sed -i -E 's/search/replace/g' filename` searches for `search` in file `filename`, it replaces the match with `replace`, `g` stands for global. What `-i` and `-E` do can be found out by typing `man sed` in your terminal: `-i` replaces in place, means in the same file; `-E` stands for using extended regex.
- `[\[A-z0-9\]:\+"]+` matches any character, any number, `[`, `]`, `:`, `+` and `"`. It will stop when the next regex part is encountered.
- `([^\\]+)` groups anything that isn't a backslash, but we must use `(\[0m[0-9]{4}[^\\]+)` because the previous regex part must know that it has to stop when it encounters `"[0m2017"`. This regex will stop before `\n`.
- `$1` is the variable that holds matching from first group (we only have one group, but if there were more they would be stored in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. by the order they occur). So the whole input string will be replaced by what we captured in first group.